# Session closing effects in WebSphere application server

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, websphere

Good evening
In our company we have an issue session-related. We have developed our application with the constraint of having only one opened instance: being the homepage the only entry point of the application (users have a modified web browser without the possibility to insert an URL), each time we open a new page from the homepage we close all the "descendants" of the javascript window object and open a new window with another operation.

We have been asked to create another entry point, so that our application can be accessed from another application (which is in another ear running on the same WebSphere instance). This would break the constraint, since we are opening a new window of my application but not from the homepage: I would have two different opened pages, with the possibility of mixing the sessions between the two calls.

The question is: is it possible to invalidate the session only of the ear of my application without affecting sessions of the other applications running on the same server instance?

Thanks a lot :)

(we use JAVA EE 1.4 and WEBSPHERE 5.1, so quite an old version - and no, we cannot change it :) )

Answer (score 0):

I must say that I cannot see clearly the model of your application, but if we reduce everything to your last question:

> is it possible to invalidate the session only of the ear of my
>   application without affecting sessions of the other applications
>   running on the same server instance?

I have spent a while looking for some way to define different session cookie names for each application deployed into a websphere 5.1, but I have had no luck.  If you find the way, you will have the answer to your question... I am sorry I can be of no more help